# Show iframe over main content on button click in React

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I'm supernew in React.
So I have a simple video frame component like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Video = ({ src }) => (
    <iframe
        allowFullScreen
        frameborder="0"
        height="315"
        src={src}
        width="560"
    />
);
export default Video;
```

And I have another button component:

```
<Button
   className="sub-category-card__button"
   onClick={()=> window.open(item.videoUrl, "_blank")}}
  >Open
</Button>
```

So now on button click I open a provided url in a new window.
But my aim is by button click open some full screen div over the main content and show video iframe component inside with provided url.
What should be inside OnClick function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `onClick` function to toggle a state variable saying whether or not the content should be displayed. Here's a simple example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [shown, setShown] = React.useState(false)
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {shown ? <VideoModal src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OZWRM2WG8Kg"/> : null}
      <button onClick={() => setShown(!shown)}>Test</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const VideoModal = (props) => {
  return <div style={{position: "fixed", top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"}}>
    <iframe
        title={props.src}
        allowFullScreen
        frameBorder="0"
        height="315px"
        src={props.src}
        width="560px"
    />
  </div>
}
```

Note that my CSS for the `VideoModal` is pretty rudimentary here and you'd want to handle the full screen modal in a more robust way than I am, but I'm assuming that the gist of the question is more about the React side of it and less about the CSS side.